# ¿Como agrego un módulo (Libreria, proyecto)?

Tags: android

Encontre la siguiente libreria que ofrece una una funcionalidad muy curiosa a los spinner es la siguiente:

https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3272

https://github.com/miteshpithadiya/SearchableSpinner

El detalle que agrego pero no correctamente, me marca un error que no encuentra un plug in

Comment: Acabo de ver esta pregunta, agregué repuesta, saludos @MarkDev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Android Studio` usa Gradle, por lo tanto puedes ver la implementación de la librería que se realiza agregando dentro del archivo `build.gradle` la siguiente dependencia :

```
compile 'com.toptoche.searchablespinner:searchablespinnerlibrary:1.3.1'
```

Seguramente se encuentran definidas otras dependencias así que ten cuidado en agregar la dependencia en el bloque `dependencies` :

**Gradle**

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.toptoche.searchablespinner:searchablespinnerlibrary:1.3.1'
    ...
}
```

después de esto simplemente tienes que sincronizar tu archivo `build.gradle` con el proyecto, mediante el botón:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

o accediendo con la secuencia:

`Tools` -> `Android` -> `Sync Project with Gradle Files`

---

En cuanto al error que comentas posteriormente:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'. >
>   Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@allowBackup
>   value=(false) from AndroidManifest.xml:20:9-36 is also present at
>   [com.toptoche.searchablespinner:searchablespinnerlibrary:1.3‌​.1]
>   AndroidManifest.xml:12:9-35 value=(true). Suggestion: add
>   'tools:replace="android:allowBackup"' to  element at
>   AndroidManifest.xml:19:5-148:19 to override

El problema aquí es que  la propiedad `tools:replace` del `AndroidManifest.xml` debe estar definida dentro de `<application>`, ejemplo:

```
   <application
        ...
        ...
        tools:replace="android:allowBackup">
```

Answer (score 0):

Tenes que agregar la dependencia dentro de tu archivo gradle:

```
dependencies {
...
compile 'com.toptoche.searchablespinner:searchablespinnerlibrary:1.3.1'
}
```

Si no te funciona trata haciendo Clean Build de tu proyecto

en el `<application>` de tu manifest agrega este atributo o modifica si existe:

```
 android:allowBackup="false"
```

Comment: si amigo no me funciono... pero intento tu recomendacion...

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@allowBackup value=(false) from AndroidManifest.xml:20:9-36
 is also present at [com.toptoche.searchablespinner:searchablespinnerlibrary:1.3.1] AndroidManifest.xml:12:9-35 value=(true).
 Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:allowBackup"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:19:5-148:19 to override.

Comment: es que no se agrega el directorio que segun en el exemplo de la libreria